# CodeIgniter How to use rand() without repeating ID

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, codeigniter

So I'm doing a quiz in CodeIgniter using MVC, so far I have this query where I get the questions from table Perguntas and I get the answers from table Resposta.

So I'm doing a quiz with 10 questions where just each one is showed individually in the View, the problem is that every time I click **next** I can get a repeated question already answered in the same quiz, so basically I´m getting repeated questions.

Any idea how to solve this without repeating the same question?

> Blockquote
>   **This is my model:**

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT PERGUNTAS.ID_PERGUNTA, PERGUNTAS.NOME_PERGUNTA, RESPOSTA.RESPOSTACERTA, RESPOSTA.RESPOSTAERRADA1, RESPOSTA.RESPOSTAERRADA2, RESPOSTA.RESPOSTAERRADA3
    FROM PERGUNTAS 
    INNER JOIN RESPOSTA
    WHERE PERGUNTAS.ID_PERGUNTA = RESPOSTA.ID_RESPOSTA
    AND PERGUNTAS.TEMA = 'Futebol'

    ORDER BY Rand() LIMIT 1");
     return $query->result();
```

> Blockquote
>   **This is my Controller**

```
public function IniciarJogoFutsal()
 {
if($this->session->userdata['logged_in']['id_util'])

    {
if($this->session->userdata['logged_in']['isadmin'] !=0)
 {
$this->load->model('Jogo_model');
$data['list'] = $this->Jogo_model->BuscarPerguntasRespostasFutsal();
$this->load->view('header_admin');
$this->load->view('jogo_futsal', $data);
 }
if($this->session->userdata['logged_in']['isadmin'] !=1)
     {  
        $this->load->model('Jogo_model');
$data['list'] = $this->Jogo_model->BuscarPerguntasRespostasFutsal();
$this->load->view('header_user');
$this->load->view('jogo_futsal', $data);
     }
    }
else
{
    redirect('Login/index');
}
}
```

> Blockquote
>   **This is part of my view `jogo_futsal` where i echo the questions when I click next question it refreshes the page**

```
<?php foreach($list as $quiz): ?>
<label style="color: #ffffff; word-wrap: break-word; transform: skew(20deg);font-weight: 900; text-shadow: 1px 0 #ffffff;"><?php echo  $quiz->NOME_PERGUNTA;?>      </label>    

<?php endforeach ?>
```

Comment: Decide on a list of questions at the start, shuffle it, store it in the session.

Comment: add for example a column "question_status" into your table and update it to 1 when question was asked. Then only show results WHERE question_status = 0

Comment: @Vickel That would affect every user globally, no?

Comment: @deceze can you show me in example of code how i can do that? Thanks btw

Comment: @deceze yes, you are right, too fast thinking... so joining/updating a table with 3 columns could help: user_id, question_id, question_status

Comment: @deceze Edited Post, when i click next button in view to the next question it refresh´s the page.